# Searching channels

Tags: search, forms, sql, ee

First time on an EE project, I want to build a search for my channel on the front end. Which is best way to achive this?

```
1 -sql via a form is this an option?

2 - 3rd party module

3. advanced search form?
```

My form is 4 dropdowns which filter the channel (jobs)

```
 -full time/part time
- qualification
- salary
- location
```

Comment: Will you also be able to search by anything else? Keywords? Could you explain in detail the search fields please?

Comment: yes the could be a keyword search in the future but at the moment it is just a simple search eg 'select * from job where type='full-time' and qualification='degree' and salary_band='4' and location='32'

Comment: I would go for the default EE seach module! I believe it can do anything you asked for!

Answer (score 1):

I've always used Solspace Super Search for all of my projects and never run into anything it couldn't do search related:

http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/

Comment: I second Super Search. Really nice add-on. Even if the native search can do what you want now, with something like Super Search you'll be confident it will be able to grow and adapt to future needs.

Answer (score 1):

While we're mentioning add-ons here, Low Search will do the job nicely.

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search